# как вставить в таблицу SQL данные полученные методом POST с формы в Java Script

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, post

Как вставить в таблицу `SQL` данные полученные методом `POST` с формы?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO user VALUES (12,' + req.body.text1 + ',' + req.body.text2 + ')\'' , function () {...
```

`console.log` показывает, что данные с формы приходят, но не вставляются в таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал переписать Ваш SQL-запрос вставки данных следующим образом:

```
var data = { ИмяСтолбца1: 12, ИмяСтолбца2: req.body.text1, ИмяСтолбца3: req.body.text2 };
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', data, function () {...});
```

В переменной `data` укажите имена столбцов из базы данных. А внутри выполняемого запроса `query` пишите `SET`. А еще после этого можно посмотреть, что было выполнено в результате с помощью `console.log`:

```
console.log(query.sql); // тут будет выведет сформированный запрос
```

Вывод сформированного запроса в `console.log(query.sql)` - только для отладки, лучше не предоставлять данную информацию посторонним личностям.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите синтаксис SQL запроса на добавление. У вас написано неправильно. Нужно примерно так: `INSERT INTO tableName (id,name) VALUES (1,'SuperMan')`